# Eclipse New Server Wizard does not accept my JDK as a JDK

Tags: eclipse, server, installation, glassfish

I am trying to configure a Glassfish Server in Eclipse, but it seems to think my JDK is a JRE. I downloaded the JDK [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk13-downloads.html). Now when pointing to it in the Wizard I get this message

[image]

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse was it? Which version of the Glassfish Tools?

Comment: My Eclipse EE is 2019-12

Glassfish tools doesnt show up in my marketplace - installed. I got it today when I created a new server and selected Glassfish Tools from the Oracle folder in the Create New Server Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it worked with JDK 8. Who needs a current version anyways am I right?